# Using reactions with discord.py slash commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Recently I have been trying to make a help command which relies on reactions to switch between pages (frankly I don't know how to make it so that buttons work). The code works properly when it is not a slash command, but the moment I change it into a slash command the add_reaction(), clear_reactions(), and remove-reaction() just don't work. I can't find anything online to figure this out.

This is the code I currently have.

```
@client.tree.command(name = "help", description = "Display the bots commands")
async def rob(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        page1 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Fun Commands:',
        description = '',
        colour = discord.Colour(0x00ffff)
        )
  
        page1.add_field(name = "Meme", value = "Sends a random meme.", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "8ball [question]", value = "Ask the 8 ball a question!", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "Hi", value = "Say hi to the bot!", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "Die", value = "Sends randomly selected quotes of last words.", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "Ping", value = "Returns your ping.", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "ABC", value = "Displays the alphabet!", inline=False)
        page1.add_field(name = "Pi", value = "Displays the first 100 digits of pi.")
        
        page2 = discord.Embed (
            title = 'Economy Commands:',
            description = '',
            colour = discord.Colour(0x00ffff)
        )

        
    
        page3 = discord.Embed (
            title = 'Moderation Commands:',
            description = '',
            colour = discord.Colour(0x00ffff)
        )

        page3.add_field(name = "kick [user]", value = "Kicks a specified user.")
        page3.add_field(name = "ban [user]", value = "Bans a specified user.")
        page3.add_field(name = "unban [user]", value = "Unbans a specified user.")
        page3.add_field(name = "clear [number]", value = "Clears a specified number of messages.")
    
        page4 = discord.Embed (
            title = "Support Server:",
            description = "",
            colour = discord.Colour(0x00ffff)
        )
        
        pages = [page1, page2, page3, page4]

        message = await interaction.response.send_message(embed = page1)
        await message.add_reaction('⏮')
        await message.add_reaction('◀')
        await message.add_reaction('▶')
        await message.add_reaction('⏭')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == interaction.user

        i = 0
        reaction = None

        while True:
            if str(reaction) == '⏮':
                i = 0
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
            elif str(reaction) == '◀':
                if i > 0:
                    i -= 1
                    await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
            elif str(reaction) == '▶':
                if i < 3:
                    i += 1
                    await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
            elif str(reaction) == '⏭':
                i = 3
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
            
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 120.0, check = check)
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
            except:
                break
        await message.clear_reactions()
```

It outputs:

```
2022-12-02 13:02:23 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'help'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 862, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\Users\human\OneDrive\Documents\EverythingBot\main.py", line 155, in rob
    await message.add_reaction('⏮')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1242, in _call        
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 887, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 880, in _do_call  
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'help' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
2022-12-02 13:04:44 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped       
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\human\OneDrive\Documents\EverythingBot\main.py", line 105, in help
    await message.clear_reactions()
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 1154, in clear_reactions        
    await self._state.http.clear_reactions(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "C:\Users\human\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 738, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50003): Cannot execute action on a DM channel
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50003): Cannot execute action on a DM channel
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the message has been responded to with `await interaction.response.`, you can't add reactions, giving this error.

```
raise InteractionResponded(self._parent)
discord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before
```

There's a simple fix to this, change

```
message = await interaction.response.send_message()
```

to

```
message = await interaction.channel.send()
```

However, if the interaction is not responded to, it will say "The application did not respond". Also, if you want to use buttons:

```
class Button_view(discord.ui.View): #"Button_view" could be changed
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = None
    #initialising
  @discord.ui.button(label='button', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, disabled=False, custom_id='button1', row=0)
  async def button1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    #after it is pressed do whatever

@tree.command(name="command", description='desc')
async def command(...):
  await interaction.response.send(content=..., view=Button_view())
```

[docs on buttons](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?%20ui%20button#discord.ui.Button)

Answer (score 0):

message = await interaction.followup.send()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).